# Is the 2-norm distance from $\ell^1$ to the harmonic sequence 0?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

I'm checking whether I understood this problem correctly. We are to consider 
$$
z=\left(1,\frac12,\frac13,\cdots\right) \in (\ell^2,\lVert\cdot\rVert_2)
$$
and
$$
Y=(\ell^1,\lVert\cdot\rVert_2)
$$
And we are to find $\mathrm{dist}(z,Y)=\inf_{y\in Y}\lVert z-y\rVert_2$.

Is it the case that the answer is 0, since we can take arbitrarily large $n$ and have $y_n\in Y$ be equal to $z$ in the first $n$ elements and 0 thereafter? I.e. 
$$
y_n = (1,\frac12,\frac13,\cdots,\frac1n,0,\cdots)
$$

Comment: In fact, you show more.  Not only is the $l^2$ distance to $l^1$ equal to zero, but the $l^2$ distance to the smaller space of sequences with finite support is also zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you say is indeed completely valid. There is nothing of substance to add as what you have written is mostly complete (just the trivial calculation missing) and entirely correct. Why did you feel uncomfortable about this? Is there something I/we can clarify?

Comment: Thanks. The classes I took in this area included almost no discussion of $\ell^p$ spaces and so without any feedback it is difficult for me to be confident in my answer.